# How to extract metadata from an image

Tags: codenameone

I'm a newbie to codenameone. I'm trying to develop some image-processing app. I need to know if the image has geotagging information and eventually extract those. Is there a way to do that in CodenameOne?

I'm aware of the methods based on plain javax.imageio packages, but I know that those are not available in codenameone.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have such an API as it's pretty different between Android/iOS. You can write something like this in pure Java and parse the image header which should be relatively simple.

Or you can build a cn1lib on top of native code e.g. see [this library](https://github.com/jsfan3/CN1Libs-VideoOptimizer/), It does that for video which is arguably harder.

Comment: Thank you, Shai, for your kind reply. Instead of starting from scratch I was looking around for some existing libraries that I could take as a starting point. I've read that "metadata-extractor" [link](https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) doesn't rely on java.io.File so maybe it's a good candidate. Do you know about it? Maybe it's a little of an overkill, as it supports dozens of file formats.

Comment: I don't know. It looks like a pretty big library so I can't really tell if it relies on features of Java that we don't support. A quick search revealed that it has some java.nio dependencies. There aren't many so it might be trivial to remove all of them but that's just one thing that might not work.